# Loading an Image inside a Jar file java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource not found

Tags: java, image, jar, lwjgl

I'm making a simple game using slick, and lwjgl. I have it running in eclipse. I am sure that my images are in the right place.  Here is what my jar file looks like : http://puu.sh/2xS3v  but I keep getting this error : http://puu.sh/2xS4v
All of my images are located in the res folder located inside the jar. Here is how I load my images : http://pastebin.com/huBDRM2W Any help is appreciated thanks :)

Comment: The answers you get will be more helpful if you include some relevant code and error messages within the actual body of the question.  It will also help future searches find your question instead of asking a new one.

Answer (score 2):

use the following code

```
ClassLoader cldr = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
java.net.URL imageURL   = cldr.getResource("/PackageB/PackageBa/PackageBaa/MyImage.png");
ImageIcon aceOfDiamonds = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
```

Comment: how do I draw that image then?

Comment: You need graphics context to draw the Image, you can override 

    paint(Graphics g)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to your situation since no code was provided, but from personal experience errors like that occur when you have some mistake in your code somewhere else preventing it from building, therefore it doesn't know that resource is there because its not registered.

Are you sure it's in the right place? The error is saying that it cant't find it so it might be in the wrong path.

Comment: I put my images into a package then exported it as a jar again. That seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I put my images into a package then exported it as a jar again. That seemed to work.